# Iterating over an array inside a JSON Object

Tags: php, arrays, json

This is the following JSON Structure over which I m trying to iterate

```
{
   "AS":{
      "Query":"vi",
      "FullResults":1,
      "Results":[
         {
            "Type":"AS",
            "Suggests":[
               {
                  "Txt":"videos",
                  "Type":"AS",
                  "Sk":""
               },
               {
                  "Txt":"vipjatt",
                  "Type":"AS",
                  "Sk":"AS1"
               },
               {
                  "Txt":"vit",
                  "Type":"AS",
                  "Sk":"AS2"
               },
               {
                  "Txt":"vijaya bank",
                  "Type":"AS",
                  "Sk":"AS3"
               },
               {
                  "Txt":"videocon d2h",
                  "Type":"AS",
                  "Sk":"AS4"
               },
               {
                  "Txt":"visarev",
                  "Type":"AS",
                  "Sk":"AS5"
               },
               {
                  "Txt":"vijaya karnataka",
                  "Type":"AS",
                  "Sk":"AS6"
               },
               {
                  "Txt":"video songs",
                  "Type":"AS",
                  "Sk":"AS7"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

And this is the code I m using to iterate over it, and trying to access the "Txt" property

```
$data = $info->get($url);
$content = json_decode($data);
$i = 0;
foreach($content->AS->Results as $item) {
$each = $item->Suggests[$i]->Txt;
    $i++;
    echo $each;
}
```

But I only get the access of the first appearance of "Txt" property.
Whats wrong with my code ? Why isint it printing every appearance of the "Txt" property??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating over the `AS->Results` items, of which there is exactly one. You want to iterate over the `Suggests` array directly:

```
foreach ($content->AS->Results[0]->Suggests as $item) {
    echo $item->Txt;
}
```

I don't know if there could be more than one item in the `Results` array. Perhaps you need to first iterate over them to pick out the right `Suggests` item to iterate over.